# Change zsh theme if too long

Tags: themes, zsh, oh-my-zsh

If I have an ohmyzsh theme that uses %~/ to get the current directory path. Is there a way to tell it that if the line length requires wrapping onto a new line, to use just the current directory without the full path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly, but Zsh can actually do something better than that! You can use [`%-X<Y<Z%<<`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html#Conditional-Substrings-in-Prompts) to ensure you always have at least X characters remaining after your prompt, by trimming the left side of Z and replacing the trimmed part with Y. (Note that Y itself is always printed literally and any [prompt escape sequences](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html) inside it will not be expanded. If you want to style Y differently from Z, you will have to put the prompt escapes before and after `%X<Y<`.)

For example:

```
PS1=$'\n%-40<...<%~%<<%# '
```

What this does:

- If expanding `%~` would leave 40 or more characters of empty space on the line, then expand it in full.
- Else, print a `...` to the left of `%~` and trim off characters from the left of `%~`'s expansion until our prompt leaves exactly 40 characters of empty space on the line.
- Always expand `%#`  after this (since it occurs after `%<<`).

The nice thing about this is that it works for the current prompt even when you resize your terminal. Just try it and you'll see it will dynamically add or remove characters as you resize.